# Problem finding unrepresented value using 3 set Venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just can't figure the logic I should be using to figure out "how many women agreed"? I was thinking the following:

Universal: $|U|=38$
Men: $|M|=16$
Black: $|B|=20$
Agree: $|A|=23$

[image: Venn Diagram]

Comment: thank you @parcly-Taxel  for the edit on how things were typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have the number of respondents for each 3-tuple from {man, woman} × {black, non-black} × {agree, disagree}, to find the number of women who agreed we sum (1) the number of black women who agreed with (2) the number of non-black women who agreed. These are regions VI and VII in the diagram, and the answer is just $8+6=14$.

Comment: wow @parcly-taxel ... I have been going crazy trying everything else I could imagine. And you nail it in 3 seconds, thank you very much for the explanation it absolutely clears it up for me.

Comment: @NateE. Now, accept my answer and we'll be done for this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 23 people who agree. From the diagram, it appears that there are 9 men who agree. Thus there must be 14 women who agree.